# Docker: Building a Go image with CGO_ENABLED=1 fails

Tags: docker, sqlite, go

I have a Go application which uses [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) library. I am able to run my application locally. However, I cannot build any docker image with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:alpine
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    gcc \
    musl-dev

WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
COPY . .

RUN go build -o ./server cmd/main.go

FROM alpine
COPY --from=0 /src/server /usr/bin/server
CMD ["server"]
```

I am getting errors as:

```
sqlite3-binding.c:34070:42: error: 'pread64' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'pread'?
sqlite3-binding.c:34088:42: error: 'pwrite64' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'pwrite'?
```

I am on MacOS 13.3.1 with M1 chip. I am not passing any `platform` arguments to `docker build`

How should I fix my `Dockerfile`?

Comment: --from=0 ? where is this stage defined ?

Comment: Have you tried including `ENV CGO_ENABLED=1` in your final stage?

Answer (score 0):

The `pread64()` and `pwrite64()` functions are extensions in GNU libc.  They aren't part of the POSIX C library standard, and they aren't available in the minimal musl libc that's included in Alpine Linux.

In a Docker context, the easiest fix for this will be to switch to a Debian- or Ubuntu-based setup.  This will be marginally larger than an Alpine-based setup (tens of megabytes) but avoids compatibility problems like these.

```bash
FROM golang:1.22-bookworm
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1

RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential \
      libsqlite3-dev

WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ./server cmd/main.go

FROM debian:bookworm
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      libsqlite3-0
COPY --from=0 /src/server /usr/bin/server
CMD ["server"]
```

I've changed the Alpine `apk` command to a Debian `apt-get` command, and I've made sure to install the C header files in the build stage and the C shared library in the final stage.  I've also added in a `RUN go mod download` line to improve Docker caching on rebuild.